# Pass data between two activities in android using Intents

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I have the following code in a Custom Array Adapter where I use a button click event to start another activity. The Array adapter is in a different package and the activity which I want to start is in a different package.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
            String savedName = getByIndex(assignments, position).getSavingName();
            Intent markingViewIntent = new Intent("com.it.AssignmentMarkingFragment.intent.action.Launch");
            markingViewIntent.putExtra("assignment", savedName);
            v.getContext().startActivity(markingViewIntent);
        }
```

Following is my manifest file.

```
<activity android:name="com.it.AssignmentMarkingFragment">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.it.AssignmentMarkingFragment.intent.action.Launch" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is how I am getting the data from the other activity inside onCreate().

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String name = extras.getString("assignment");
```

But the value of name is always null. Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Print  at first `String savedName`

Comment: check TextUtils.isEmpty(savedname) and then put that extra